# Adding Two Elements in an Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a method that adds the two last elements of two arrays together and add the sum on another array. But if the two elements are more than 10, then I would need to carry that number to the next array.

This program should be similar to what an odometer does.

Here is my sample code.

```
int [] sum(int []number1, int []number2)
{   
    int [] total;
    int carry = 0;
    for ( int k = numbers1 - 1; k >= 0; k++)
    {
        sum = number1[k] + number2[k] + carry;
        carry = sum/10;
        total[k] = sum
    }
    return total;
}
```

An example output would be:

***0 1 2 3 4***

0 8 9 9 9

4 5 7 0 3

5 4 7 0 2

So the top array is just a visual aid that tells where the position for the number is.
The program is suppose to add the next two arrays together. i.e. 9 + 3 = 12
Since 12 is above 9, it carries over the 10 to the next set of arrays, that is why the third array only has a 2 in its place, and that is why the next array is 9 + 0 = 0; because the 10 was carried over.

I am not sure why my code won't work. I don't get the right numbers. Could anyone give any hints or solution to the problem?

-Thanks

Comment: What is `carry` initialized to? And what values are you passing in?

Comment: can you provide your *real* code? It has many typos and is hard to track a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `numbers1` is the number of elements in the array.
In this case it should be `k--` instead of `k++` because you are starting from the last element and moving backword.